# Parabolic sprite movement of swipe with speed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I want to move a sprite with swipe gesture, like it start from one place and with angle it end with trajectory, I really don't know where to start this thats why i am not posting any code here. Any direction or piece of code will be appreciated. Note: Should I use cocos2d for this or any physics engine like box2d or chipmunk would be needed?

Regards

Comment: Cocos2D will be fine. You may be able to do it with CoreAnimation also. What you will need to do is go out and try something. When you get stuck you can then come back here and ask a question about what you are stuck with.

Comment: can you tell me about parabolic movement of sprite, how to implement it. any direction?

Comment: Well, there are many, many, many other things you will need to do before you can get parabolic movement of sprites. Do you have an app already? Are there sprites in it? Can you display the sprites onto the screen? Can they move? If you answer no to any of these then I'd suggest going back and starting an app and getting to a point where the sprites move.

Comment: i can move the sprite normally and with bezier curve, this is how i can get parabolic movement somehow. but since i have to move sprite with swipe, i don't know control points which bezier curve need to move. thats why i m stuck here. I need to know what should i try to get parabolic movement.

Comment: Ah, so, I'd suggest going and editing your original question to put in as much information as possible about what you are doing already. That will give us some hope of being able to help you :D P.S. Bezier curves are probably not the way to go but I'll wait for you to update the question.

Comment: i think you have understand my question now, please edit my question and if possible answer it :)

Comment: Only you know what you are currently doing. Update the question so I know which answer to provide. Thanks

Comment: please just tell me how to move a sprite in parabolic path.

Comment: How can I do that without knowing what you are doing already?! Seriously, I'm not trying to be awkward. I do not know what type of app you are making, I don't know if you are using an engine or CoreAnimation or just UIKit? If you are using Cocos2D do you have an update loop? Without you actually providing information about what you are doing there is literally no way of me answering the question.

Comment: i m using coco2d. Yes i have update loop.

Comment: "If I read the question properly"?!?! You ask about cocos2d, box2d and chipmunk. Which part of that tells me what you are doing? Where is the code that you are currently using to move the sprites? Which one of the three engines that you mentioned are you actually using? Please don't tell me to read the question properly when you haven't written it properly to begin with. I tried to help by asking for more information. You obviously don't want me to help. Maybe you will update the question and get an answer from someone else.

Comment: please respectfully leave this conversation because you are making simple thing complex. Linear movement of sprite have nothing to do with parabolic movement.

Comment: Linear movement has everything to do with parabolic movement. Please learn how to ask a question and how to not insult the people who are trying to help you. Don't worry, I won't be coming back here.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you start here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials. There are tons of great a well explained tutorials to help you get started with cocos2d. I might recommend looking into using a physics engine like Box2D. An introduction tutorial is here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls.